# JPA: Aggregate entities in select query, with optional associations

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, join

given the following JPA entities:

1. A, with fields id, name
2. B, with fields id, name and 1-1 association a to A (one instance of B always exists for any instance of A)
3. C, with fields id, name and 1-1 association a to A (but one instance of C does not always exists for any instance of A)

I would like to have in a single query the id's and names of the 3 associated entities for all instances of type A, like:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name, c.id, c.name from A a, B b, C c 
where b.a=a and c.a=a
```

Since associations can't be bidirectional, we can't use JOINs from A to B and C, so we need to select from all the three entities (left outer JOIN could help, otherwise).

This is working well when all the 3 instances exists for a given instance of type A, but when there is no C instance for a given A, the query returns nothing.

Is there any way to configure the query so that it allows optional entities in the select clause? Or, is there any different way to define the query to return the requested values?

TIA.
Daniele